# Golang: gccgo и gc

Tags: golang, сборщик-мусора

Есть ли у `gccgo` какие-то преимущества в плане производительности или безопасности в сравнении с `gc`?

Comment: ох. ответ будет очень большим. на статью потянет. но попробую позже написать

Answer (score 1):

вся суть gccgo в том, чтобы скомпилировать ваше приложение под конкретную железу. Это позволяет быстрее сделать вычисления, особенно математические, но страдают другие части приложения. Основное преимущество перед gccgo — это [escape analysis](http://www.agardner.me/golang/garbage/collection/gc/escape/analysis/2015/10/18/go-escape-analysis.html)

`gccgo` применяет больше правил и инструкций при комплияции, больше оптимизирует ваш код. Взамен вам требуется больше времени на процесс компиляции, чем при встроенном `gc`. Также `gccgo` поддерживает почти все процессоры, которые поддерживает GCC, а вот `gc` в основном x86(32-bit и 64-bit) и ARM.

так как `gc` входит в поставку с новыми версиями, а `gccgo` "допиливатся" потом, то второй всегда отстает от официальных релизов.

прочитать про [бенчмарки](https://dave.cheney.net/tag/gccgo) 
прочитать про [gccgo](https://habr.com/ru/company/intel/blog/348230/)
еще одна полезная [статья](https://golang.org/doc/go1.3#gccgo)